# how can i play this in internet explorer?

Tags: html, flash

can u please help me, how to play this in internet explorer?
any suggestions to play this in other player

```
<iframe name="go4entFrm" src="http://go4ent.com/frames/go4entFrm.php?urls=363633&amp;isdwnld=true&amp;siteName1=MUSICKING.IN" border="0" frameborder="0" height="366" scrolling="no" width="458"></iframe>
```

please help me.....
below is the original code for above source

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript"> 
<!--
function dispMega(url)
{
    document.getElementById("frame").innerHTML='<iframe name="link_url" src="megaFrame.php?url='+url+'" border="0" frameborder="0" height="350" width="476" scrolling="no"></iframe>';
}

function dispVeoh(url)
{
    document.getElementById("frame").innerHTML='<iframe name="link_url" src="veohFrame.php?url='+url+'" border="0" frameborder="0" height="347" width="482" scrolling="no"></iframe>';
}
//-->
</script>
<style> 
body
{ margin: 0; padding: 0; background:#000000;overflow:auto}
</style>

</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<!-- Print Megavideo -->

<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" height="100%" width="100%" bgcolor="#000000"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="flashvars" value="autoPlay=false&browser=IE&isdwnld=&urls=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&siteName1=&siteLink=" /><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="movie" value="http://go4ent.com/flashPlayer/go4entPublic.swf" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" /><param name="loop" value="false" /><embed src="http://go4ent.com/flashPlayer/go4entPublic.swf" flashvars="autoPlay=false&browser=IE&isdwnld=&urls=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&siteName1=&siteLink="  quality="high" bgcolor="#000000" height="100%" width="100%" loop="false" allowScriptAccess="always" allowFullScreen="true" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></embed></object>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain, in more detail, what you're trying to do?  Are you having problems viewing that HTML snippet with IE?

Comment: when i open that in ie its asking for firefox to install

Comment: Nothing you can do about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Flash player in the URL above check's the user agent to see what browser the user is using.

If it detects Internet Explorer it raises an error (however it works fine in Firefox and Safari).

The creator of the Flash player has deliberately coded it that way and there isn't anything practical you can do about it.